# Возвращаемое значение json_encode разное

Tags: php, json-encode

Ситуация такая. Есть сайт, на нем все работает нормально. Обычная функция загрузки, отрабатывает нормально. В Консоли json_encode возвращает вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом был куплен домен с хостингом у другого провайдера. Сайт перенесли, все работает, но вот функция загрузки изображения не работает. Код идентичен, и json_encode возвращает вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в какую сторону капать? Есть подозрения на то что были разные версии PHP

Comment: Просто формат возвращаемых данных не JSON. Можно попробовать в JS `dataType` прописать.

Comment: и в чем разница то? начните с того как вы получили этот вывод в консоли. JSON  с виду идентичен. Если это был какой-то аякс запрос с jquery, то данная библиотека пытается автоматически распознать формат, и обычно ей это удается. Так что возможно перед выводом этого контента есть еще каике-то символы или какой-то текст (вызванный сменой хостинга), которые препятствует автоматическому парсингу. Также вероятно, что при выдаче этого Json на стороне сервера вы не устаналвиаете content-type ответа, хотя для jquery это не требуется, обычно, но желательно. Конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: @teran суть в том, что есть два идентичных сайта. Код одинаковый, но они на разных серверах. на одно все работает норм, на другом нет.

Comment: пишите код нормально, а не надейтесь на авось. отдали json - поставьте заголовок соответствующий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно либо настроить веб-сервер, чтобы определял MIME-type как `application/json`, либо в коде перед выводом JSON-данных передавать заголовок `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема в том что json возвращается нормальный, но браузер (и jQuery) не понимают что это json и работают с ним как с простым текстом.
Вам нужно передавать заголовок `Content-Type: application/json`.

Если на предедущем хостинге работало, а на новом нет, попробуйте включить опцию `output_buffering`.

---

Дело в том, что протокол http устроен так, что сначала нужно отправить заголовки, а потом тело запроса. То есть сначала отправляются заголовки типа `Content-Type`, `Set-cookie`, `Location`, а потом идет вывод, например контента через `echo` или другими способами.
**Но** после того как начался вывод, отправка заголовков игнорируется, так как нельзя отправить заголовок, потом кусок тела запроса, потом еще заголовок и так далее. Должен быть порядок.
Для примера, вот такой код отправит заголовок `Content-type`, напишет json, но редирект не сделает.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo $someJson;
header("Location: /error404");
```

Для решения такой проблемы в php.ini (значит, и настройках в панели хостига) существует параметр output buffering - буферизация вывода. Она сохраняет все заголовки на одну кучу, тело запроса в другую кучу, и когда скрипт закончит работу - отправит всё вместе.